# Brownian Motion on closed planar curves

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, polygons

Is it possible to simulate brownian motion on initial state polygons (with many vertices in a small space: >200 vertices in a 1x1 euclidian space) and standard closed curves in 2d?

Any direction on this issue will be greatly appreciated

Comment: @JitendraSingh I am at the beginning stages of this query and have not been able to find any helpful info on the internet. I may just be researching incorrectly, but I'm not sure